# What is the accepted difference between training accuracy and testing accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

My ANN model is giving accuracy of 98% with training data and 94% accuracy with testing data. Does this mean Overfitting?

Answer (score 3):

There's no single difference accepted. It always depends on your model, training, setup, etc.

It's common that the model does a little bit of overfitting.
To decide I usually look at the graph. If the accuracty on testing data started moving away for the accuracy on training data that is a sign of over-fitting. I usually try to stop training around the point where they start diverging. If they are moving together then you are usually still good on over-fitting.

For your case, is 94% an acceptable accuracy? If yes, then you have a good model. If not then you either need to train it for longer or apply some of the common techniques for fighting overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Dataset you are one and the size of it. On small datasets I would say this is acceptable since your "randomly" pully test data out of your datasets and it could happen that you just had bad luck. On bigger datasets 4% is definitly a lot and you should figure out what is happening before hand. Maybe try to introduce a validation dataset, which you run after every epoch!